# Help interpreting diagram of compressive forces in bone

Tags: free-body-diagram

I am trying to understand where I should draw my arrows for a free body of the following picture

[image]

But I've never tried to draw free body diagram to explain these kinds of curvy lines.  I think if I could understand one example I would be able to do it in the future. But I'm really not sure what the blue and red curvy lines signify.

Can someone help me understand what exactly these lines represent about the force of the pelvis on top of the femoral head?

Here's another version of the lines

[image]

Comment: A free body diagram won't do much good here. What you need is continuum mechanics. Having said that, biophysics is a discipline of its own, really. I am not voting to close in case somebody can give you a few good pointers of where to look for a good treatment of this kind of problem.

Comment: @CuriousOne: "continuum mechanics": Finite Element Analysis? I might have an intuitive bash at this tomorrow.

Comment: @Gert: To actually calculate something to more than zeroth order on this one? Yeah, that's going to be done by a computer, I am afraid.

Comment: @CuriousOne can you elaborate on why free body diagrams don't work here? I suspected continuum mechanics would be needed but I don't know much about it or if it is practical to use without a computer